# How to use a numeric array as a form input name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Looked through many of the questions about this - and could not find a real answer.  So here goes...

I have a form where I will be dynamically adding sections (in this case "attendee information") and so I wanted to use names like `firstName[0]`, `firstName[1]`, etc.  I have already written the code to add the sections with a new numeric index for each.

However...

When I attempt to use JQuery (or just plain JS) to read the values of any of the form fields (dynamically created or not), I'm getting undefined.  If I change the names to `firstName1`, `firstName2`, etc., it works.  Only when I use the numeric array indexes.. nada.

I've tried...

```
$('#firstName[' + indexNum + ']')val();
$('input[name=firstName[' + indexNum + ']]').val();
```

.. and a couple other things.  (And yes, the ID is the same as the name.)

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: As an aside, it's a bad naming convention that you've chosen. The HTML id will look like a JavaScript index. Why not just name the elements: `firstName1` and `firstName2`, etc.?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks for that Scott - but I was trying to find a much simpler way to uses the arrays to loop over and save info (based on results) to different tables.  This seemed simpler than parsing the names with potentially unknown numbers.

Comment: Thanks to others for pointing out questions I simply didn't see.  Just when you think you've covered the research questions..  ugh.  Thanks all for the help - as usual.

Comment: You are much better off following convention here. Give elements `id` that are unique and expressive. Don't worry about gathering them all up into an array later as this is very easy using `document.querySelectorAll(selector)`. Once they are in the array, looping is a no-brainer. Trust me, the more you try to make the names work as you've described, the more pain you are in for down the road.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks for that tip Scott.. I'll look at that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Category:Attribute](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

> Attribute values in selector expressions must follow the rules for W3C
>   CSS selectors; in general, that means anything other than a [valid
>   identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) should be surrounded by quotation marks.
>
> - double quotes inside single quotes: `$('a[rel="nofollow self"]')`
> - single quotes inside double quotes: `$("a[rel='nofollow self']")`
> - escaped single quotes inside single quotes: `$('a[rel=\'nofollowself\']')`
> - escaped double quotes inside double quotes:    `$("a[rel=\"nofollow self\"]")`
>
> The variation you choose is generally a matter of style or
>   convenience.

---

Try wrapping value of attribute in single quotes `'firstName[" + indexNum + "]'`

```js
var indexNum = 0;

console.log($("input[name='firstName[" + indexNum + "]']").val())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input name="firstName[0]" value="abc" />
```

alternatively escape `[` and `]` characters with two backslash `\\` characters

```js
var indexNum = 0;

console.log($("input[name=firstName\\[" + indexNum + "\\]]").val())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input name="firstName[0]" value="abc" />
```

Comment: While this says some of the same things as Zakaria's answer, I'm going to choose this one due to it being more complete.  Zakaria's answer is great as well.  Wish I could mark two answers!

Answer (score 1):

You should add double quotes :

```
$('input[name="firstName[' + indexNum + ']"]').val();
______________^___________________________^
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
  alert($('input[name="firstName[' + i + ']"]').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="firstName[0]" value="11"/>
<input type="text" name="firstName[1]" value="22"/>
<input type="text" name="firstName[2]" value="33"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is indicated in [Jquery page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), "[" and "]" are special characters and must be escaped in order to be used as a name of an element.

You should use:

```
$('#firstName\\[' + indexNum + '\\]')val();
$('input[name=firstName\\[' + indexNum + '\\]]'
```